# How to call command with double and single quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I've been trying to write shell scripts for IBM License Use Management. Scripts will run on Cygwin/Windows. Some arguments (those containing spaces in particular) need to be passed with both double and single quotes. The following works in the commandline and also as a complete command in the script:

```
i4blt -Al -v "'Dassault Systemes'" -p "PR1 VER123"
```

But the same would not work when I try the vendor name argument as a variable, i.e. VENDOR="\"'Dassault Systemes'\"" or anything like that. So the following:

```
VENDOR="\"'Dassault Systemes'\""
PRODUCT="\"PR1 VER123\""
i4blt -Al -v $VENDOR -p $PRODUCT
```

returns this:

```
Vendor "'Dassault not found
```

I tried escaping the quotes, passing as arguments to a function, and many more solution candidates from Stackoverflow. The program I'm trying to run from the script (i4blt) insists on evaluating only the first part of the variable, until the space. 
Ideas appreciated.

Comment: You might want to quote the variables when you use them, e.g: `i4blt -Al -v "$VENDOR" -p "$PRODUCT"`

Comment: Mm, thanks, but it doesn't work either. Here's the response:  
// ADM-10110: Please enter flag -v followed by vendor information

Comment: `VENDOR="'Dassault Systemes'"` and then `i4blt -Al -v "$VENDOR" -p "$PRODUCT"` should work. No need to write the double quotes in the variable.

Comment: @octinum ‘Doesn't work’ won't help us help you. Describe in what way it doesn't work. If you want to troubleshoot, I suggest using `set -x` and/or replacing `i4blt` with `echo`.

Comment: @Biffen; I thought the response was self-explanatory, sorry. i4blt program expects a "Vendor information", as "'Dassault Systemes'" after -v switch. Somehow it does not get it; I'm looking for the reason as well. 
Anyway; Biffen's suggestion and fedorqui's solution seems to work. I'm going to mark as answer if he/she writes it as an answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `i4blt` with variables, they will be expanded into their values, including their spaces, and Bash will split the arguments by spaces.

Thus

```
VENDOR="\"'Dassault Systemes'\""
PRODUCT="\"PR1 VER123\""
i4blt -Al -v $VENDOR -p $PRODUCT
```

Will run `i4blt` with the following arguments:

1. `-Al`
2. `-v`
3. `"'Dassault`
4. `Systemes'"`
5. `-p`
6. `"PR1`
7. `VER123"`

(Including the quotes, since that's how the variables were set.)

To make each expanded variable a *single* argument, you need to quote it:

```
i4blt -Al -v "$VENDOR" -p "$PRODUCT"
```

The arguments will then be:

1. `-Al`
2. `-v`
3. `"'Dassault Systemes'"`
4. `-p`
5. `"PR1 VER123"`

(Once again including the quotes.)